# After 15.04 update: Aliased/choppy icons

Tags: gnome, icons, gtk, 15.04

Just updated to 15.04, and my icons are all aliased/choppy looking now. I tried purging and reinstalling my icon themes, and I keep seeing this warning:

```
gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid.
```

Even switching back to the default Ubuntu icons has the same issue - all aliased.

Screenshot...you can even see it in the application switcher, although it improves as icons approach their native resolutions:

[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrading.

Comment: Do you have Intel/NVIDIA graphics too?

Comment: Yes, two separate AMD/ATI Cards, a Radeon 6450 and a 6400

Comment: Hm weird. Wonder what's causing this.

Comment: Me too.  I did "clean-install" 15.04 and use compiz-gnome and gnome-panel, rather than Unity.  When I add custom application launcher for my app and choose an icon, different icon is used by gnome.  ~/.config/gnome-panel/launchers/my-app.desktop looks two entries for icon, one is "Icon[ja]=nm-no-connection" and the other is "Icon=network-idel".  Apparently, there is no icon path which I chose.

Comment: What icon pack is that? Does the same happen with a completely different one? Are you using the additional drivers?

Comment: Happens with any icon pack, and with the stock Intel drivers, Nouveau driver, or NVIDIA driver. All other drivers are stock.

Comment: same here with the stock icons: http://i.imgur.com/lgoeA2W.png

Comment: I run Ubuntu 14.04 but with HWE kernel support and it happened to me too after recent kernel upgrade, fun fact is that only affected icon packs that have `.png` or alike format. I have a few created on my own and they also started to look choppy but all of the rest were fine I'm using FlatWoken icon set and all the icons have `.svg` format funny but when I reset my personal created icons to all FlatWoken ones everything back to normal. Don't know if that help you but in my case as stated it doesn't affect icon sets with `.svg` format alike.

Comment: I'm just keeping my icons in one of the 2 sizes where they look reasonable. Sad this hasn't been fixed yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ever thought of installing another desktop then reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop? I don't know if this will work, but it might be worth a try.  For example, you can execute the following commands to install the Lubuntu desktop environment:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you don't want to use the Lubuntu desktop, then you can choose a different desktop environment (such as "Ubuntu") at the login screen. That idea might just work.

Answer (score 1):

turned out it was the icon set! Which is weird because the issue affected 2 different icon sets I tried before, so I assumed that wasn't the problem.

Just wanted to post this to help anyone else who runs into this frustrating issue.

Comment: Click the checkbox to accept this as an answer, please. Then it won't show up as an unanswered question and others will see that it has an accepted answer so they'll find it easier.

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then one by one run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ci/stable
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop
```

This will install the lxde plasma 5 desktop.

Answer (score 1):

On newer versions of Ubuntu, you should be using icon packs that use .svg files instead of .png files or you will have this issue.

So, make sure the icon set uses .svg files to avoid this issue.